# Every 48 hours toggle between three classList

Tags: javascript

I am looking to build an ongoing timer throughout the year. Every 48 hours I want the ID of a span to be active.

I have this working on a 24-hour schedule that changes letters. The code cycles through the current hour and checks it against my else if to toggle which letter should be styled .active.

How could I modify this timer to be 48 hours long and display letter A for 48 hours then switch to B and stay for 48 hours then switch to C for 48 hours and then back to A? Thanks for any suggestions!

Forgot to mention this would start at 8am and run until 8am for 48 hours straight.

```
const today = new Date();
const hourNow = today.getHours()
const letterA = document.querySelector('#A');
const letterB = document.querySelector('#B');
const letterC = document.querySelector('#C');
const allLetters = document.querySelectorAll("span");

if (hourNow > 18) {
  letterA.classList.toggle('active');
} else if (hourNow > 12) {
  letterB.classList.toggle('active');
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
  letterC.classList.toggle('active');
} else {
  allLetters.forEach(letter => {
    letter.removeAttribute('class');
  })
}
```

Comment: You need to work with timestamps.

Comment: Yeah @pavel is right use `Date.now()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way for this to work using a countdown to a future date:

```js
const today = new Date();
const now = today.getTime();
const letterA = document.querySelector('#A');
const letterB = document.querySelector('#B');
const letterC = document.querySelector('#C');

// Set countdown til 8am at the end of the year 9999 (or whenever)
const countDownDate = new Date("December 31, " + 9999 + " 07:00:00").getTime();

// Find the distance between now an the countdown date
const timeLeft = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculation for days left
const daysLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

// A, B, C
const numberOfSpans = 3;

// if we wanted to change every day, we'd need:
// (daysLeft % numberOfSpans)

// since we want to change every 2 days, we'll need:
const daysLeftOver = (daysLeft % (numberOfSpans * 2));

// remove all active classes
if (letterA.classList.contains("active")) {
  letterA.classList.remove("active");
}
if (letterB.classList.contains("active")) {
  letterB.classList.remove("active");
}
if (letterC.classList.contains("active")) {
  letterC.classList.remove("active");
}

// Add active class to whichever box

// 0,1
if (daysLeftOver == 0 || daysLeftOver == 1) {
  letterA.classList.toggle('active');
  // 2,3
} else if (daysLeftOver == 2 || daysLeftOver == 3) {
  letterB.classList.toggle('active');
  // 4,5
} else if (daysLeftOver == 4 || daysLeftOver == 5) {
  letterC.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
span {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span id="A">A</span>
<span id="B">B</span>
<span id="C">C</span>
```

Comment: I studied this code and tested it out and I am wondering if you could help me clarify how this works exactly at 8am. For example, I changed year 9999 to 3999 and daysLeftOver went from 5 to 2 so this code is very helpful and very close to what I need but I am struggling to figure out how to get it working starting at 8am and runs every 48 hours until 8am and changes letters so every 6 days is a cycle.

Comment: @Eric No problemo. The `countDownDate` variable in my example is set to count us down to a date far in the future. I selected December 31st, 9999 at 08:00.00 (8 am) randomly. So the  `new Date("December 31, " + 9999 + " 08:00:00")` is used to give us back the number of days between today and 8 am on the future date. By using the modulo (%) operator with the days left and the number of days in a row that you want one thing to have the `.active` class (in your case, 2), we can get the remainder which will be between 0 and 5.

Comment: As an example, if your future date is 6 days in the future, then `6 % 6` will return 0. And if it's 5 days in the future, `5 % 6` will return 5. And `4 % 6` will return 4... etc. etc.. In this case, December 31, 9999 is 2,914,115 days in the future (as of today), and `2,914,115 % 6` is 5. And the date you picked is 722,660 days in the future. And `722,660 % 6` is 2.

Comment: So tomorrow the value of the remainder will be 4 since `2,914,114 % 6` equals 4.
Also, to have unix time switch you over right at 8am, I had to change the `08:00:00` to `07:00:00`. I fixed it in my answer above.

Comment: I also fixed a typo I had in the logic at the end.

[Here's a pen I made explaining it](https://codepen.io/leimapapa/pen/qBrojpz)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I ended up using it and added some more logic to track not only today but tomorrow as well. Your original code needs a tiny fix. In your current code it tracks CBA instead of ABC. I fixed this by doing  0 || 1 = A, 2 || 3 = C, 4 || 5 = B.